# Hook variable call in PHP

Tags: php, autoload, magic-methods

what i'm trying to archive is kind of an autoloader for variables in php. is there any way to hook the loading of variables in php?

example usage would be:

```
function __autoloadVar($varname,$indices){
    global $$varname;

    if(count($indices) > 0 && !isset($$varname[$indices[0]])){ //first index
        $$varname[$indices[0]] = load_var_content($indices[0]); //this would call a function that loads a variable from the database, or another source
    }
}

echo $foo["bar"]["baz"];
// => calls __autoloadVar("foo",array("bar","baz")) then accessing it
```

is there any hook to archive this?

[EDIT]:
the use case would be that i'm trying to refactor the loading of language properties. they're stored in files, which have become pretty pumped and memory intensive, since they are always completely loaded, even if they're unused.

Exchanging all the variables with a function call would not work, since that would need months to replace everywhere, especially because search and replace won't work if the variables are embedded in strings.

Another refacturing will be to move the variables to the database, which can be done in a script. but the loading process to load all variables at once would hit way too hard in the runtime.

Comment: No, there isn't. If you explained your use case or context in more detail, someone might be able to advise a nicer alternative though.

Comment: i added our specific use case

Comment: @Mr.Manhattan You should be coding outside of global variable namespace very close to 100% of time, so what would this give you?

Comment: @Marek well, I do...the crowds of developers before me didn't. And we're talking about 4000 files+ of a project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to make `$foo` somewhat "magical", if you know its structure:

```
class Foo implements ArrayAccess {
  private $bar;

  public function offsetGet($name) {
    switch($name) {
      case "bar":
        if(empty($this->bar)) $this->bar = new FooBar;
        return $this->bar;
    }
  }
  public function offsetExists($offset) {  }
  public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {  }
  public function offsetUnset($offset) {  }
}

class FooBar implements ArrayAccess {
  private $baz;

  public function offsetGet($name) {
    switch($name) {
      case "baz":
        if(empty($this->baz)) $this->baz = new FooBarBaz;
        return $this->baz;
    }
  }
  public function offsetExists($offset) {  }
  public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {  }
  public function offsetUnset($offset) {  }
}

class FooBarBaz {
  public function __toString() {
    return "I'm FooBarBaz\n";
  }
}

$foo = new Foo;
echo $foo['bar']['baz'];
```

What everything is possible with this approach is left as an exercise.

Comment: The first class is already enough, since i only need the first index. This is the perfect approach i was looking for.